# Keyboard not opening for WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

I have tried the fix by adding `webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` and touch listener. It works only for the first time. When I navigate to some other fragment and come back to the webview keyboard is not opening while clicking the input field. Still, I am able to see the cursor blinking. My webview is a part of a recycler view and put inside its view holder.

```
wv_svg.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv_svg.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        wv_svg.setFocusable(true);
        wv_svg.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        wv_svg.setClickable(true);
        WebSettings settings = wv_svg.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wv_svg.clearHistory();
        wv_svg.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(context), "Android");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            wv_svg.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            wv_svg.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        wv_svg.loadUrl(url);
        wv_svg.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        wv_svg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                           v.requestFocus();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add these lines to your webview

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```